# How to Split String SQL from to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how to split one value from sql?

EX: column SQL

[image]

Now, I want split to

[image]

Code:

```
declare @ND nvarchar(max)= N'AA (AA11) [37100]'
select substring(@ND,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',@ND)-2) as Name
      ,substring(@ND,patindex('%[0-9]%',@ND),len(@ND)) as Number
```

Comment: can you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: What are the roles for the split? what version of SQL Server are you using? Please post proper sample data (as DDL+DML) and formatted text for desired results instead of images. Also, it would help to see what you've already tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `CHARINDEX()`, `REPLACE()`, `LEN()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions as

```
SELECT Str FullName,
       REPLACE(Str, SUBSTRING(Str, CHARINDEX('[', Str), CHARINDEX(']', Str)), '') Name,
       SUBSTRING(Str, CHARINDEX('[', Str) + 1, LEN(Str) - CHARINDEX('[', Str)-1) Number
FROM (VALUES('BBB(15CC)[222]'), ('AA[1111]')) T(Str);
```

OR

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Str FullName,
         LEFT(Str, CHARINDEX('[', Str) -1) Name
  FROM (VALUES('BBB(15CC)[222]'), ('AA[1111]')) T(Str)
)
SELECT FullName,
       Name,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(FullName, Name + '[', ''), ']', '') Number
FROM CTE;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------------+-----------+--------+
|    FullName    |   Name    | Number |
+----------------+-----------+--------+
| BBB(15CC)[222] | BBB(15CC) |    222 |
| AA[1111]       | AA        |   1111 |
+----------------+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @t table (fullname varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('AA [1111]')
insert into @t values ('BB(15CC) [2222]')

select 
    fullname,
    substring(fullname,1,CHARINDEX('[',fullname)-1) Name,
    replace(substring(fullname,CHARINDEX('[',fullname)+1,len(fullname)),']','') as number 
from @t
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your code only answer will greatly help the OP understand what your answer does here.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample data, the last 6 characters are always square braces with the number.  If this is always the case, you can use simpler logic:

```
select left(fullname, len(fullname) - 7),
       left(right(fullname, 5), 4)
from @t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9794f14af5556f2d1f1bb523f82fdc6d) is a db<>fiddle.

For a more general case, I would also want to handle the situation where there is no `[` in the string without generating an error:

```
select left(fullname, charindex('[', fullname + '[') - 1),
       replace(stuff(fullname, 1, charindex('[', fullname + '['), ''), ']', '')
from @t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d727bb4c8b632f13cf8b8faf31acb44) is another db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml conversion we can get the expected result

```
Declare @t table (fullname varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('AA [1111]')
insert into @t values ('BB(15CC) [2222]')


SELECT DISTINCT Fullname,
       Split.a.value('/S[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Name,
       Split.a.value('/S[2]','nvarchar(100)') AS Number
FROM
(
SELECT Fullname,
        CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Fullname,' ','</S><S>')+'</S>','[',''),']','') AS XML ) AS FullnameData
FROM @t
)AS A
CROSS APPLY FullnameData.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
```

Result

```
Fullname            Name        Number
----------------------------------------
AA [1111]           AA          1111
BB(15CC) [2222]     BB(15CC)    2222
```